# find_element_by_xpath unable to locate

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram, geckodriver

im trying to start a bot to accept cookies on instagram.

I have been succesful using this code

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep (5)
accept_cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept All']")
accept_cookies.click()
```

This works as expected however when converted to a function in a seperate file it seems to cause an issue.

File A now looks like

```
from File_B import click_accept_cookies
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

click_accept_cookies()
```

File_B looks like

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

def click_accept_cookies():
    sleep(5)
    accept_cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept All']")

    accept_cookies.click()
```

The error i run into is  `Unable to locate element: //a[text()='Log in']`
Can anyone see the mistake?

Edit: Thank you for everyone who responded, i made it work due to your suggestions. Stack overflow has the best community.

Comment: what issue are you running into?

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: You are creating 2 instance of the browser in your files. Remove it from File_B

Comment: `it seems to cause an issue` -> please provide the error message. Also, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass browser variable as parameter to "click_accept_cookies" function. Remove below lines from file B

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```